# How to move commit from one branch to another?

Tags: git

there.
I made a mistake in Git.
I had a code in Development branch, on which i was working
And i needed to use git command

```
git branch newBranch
git checkout newBranch
git add .
git commit -m 'something'
git push origin newBranch
```

To push my changes from newBranch
And instead of this i excedently wrote

```
 git add .
 git commit -m 'something'
```

Is there a way how to send it from newBranch ?

I tried to move from Development branch to newBranch and run same commands, but it didn't work:(

Comment: it's not clear what you did and neither it's clear what you meant to do instead

Comment: @Dieg De Vita I needed to push my changes which were in Development branch  from newBranch and instead of it i made a commit in Development

Comment: if you didn't push your wrong commit, you can still revert to the previous state on a given branch doing `git reset --soft HEAD~1`. That will undo the latest commit on that branch. After that you'll find your now uncommitted changes.. checkout to the branch where you are meant to commit those changes and just do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to push to any branch from any branch. A fast method I generally use would be to

```sh
git checkout -b someBranch origin/newBranch
git add -A
git commit -m "SupDo"
git push origin someBranch
```

Now, there could be some rule upstream that prevents you from pushing to the branch in question. If lets say, you wanted to move `development` branch to `newBranch1`, you can simply

```sh
git checkout -b newBranch1 origin/development
git add -A
git commit -m "Init newBranch1"
git push origin newBranch1
```

newBranch1 should have everything from origin/development.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: As well, if you have committed to a branch unintentionally, simply do a `git log branchname` find the commit before the one you accidently made and reset the branch to that hash by running the following. 

```
git checkout branchWithBadCommit
git reset --hard COMMITHASH 
git add -A
git commit -m "Reverting to Good Commit"
git push -f origin branchName
```